# Moving autogenerated build files from one git repo to another git repo

Tags: git, version-control

I want to move the auto generated files from git repo-A to git repo-B. Git repo-A generates build directory after **make** but that build directory is not checked in. I spent lot of time in investigation a method to do but I wasn't able to do.

```
GIT repo-A:
    |------directoryA
    |------directoryA1
    |------build/ (autogenerated after make)

GIT repo-B:
    |------directoryB
    |------directoryB1
    |------repo-A:build/ (want this directory from A to B)
```

[Actually I followed this link to filter the directory but it didn't work](http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/.)

Clone the repo-A into repo-B and then filter the directory I want but unfortunately the final binaries generated in build directory of repo-A is not checked in.

Is there any way I can able to move build non checked in directory to another repo ?

I'm willing to use it as sub modules also if it solves my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the branch (assume it’s develop branch) including build folder in repo-A as a subtree in repo-B:

```
# in repo-B
git subtree add --prefix=repo-A:build/ <URL for repo-A> develop
```